# Reshaping a multiindex pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a multiindex pandas dataframe that looks like this

```
 ID            I                   II                  III
 METRIC        a    b    c    d    a    b    c    d    a    b    c    d
 2015-08-01    0    1    2    3    20   21   22   23   40   41   42   43
 2015-08-02    4    5    6    7    24   25   26   27   44   45   46   47
 2015-08-03    8    9    10   11   28   29   30   31   48   49   50   51
```

where it is indexed by the dates (`2015-08-01`, `2015-08-02`, `2015-08-03`, etc.), the first-level columns (`I`, `II`, `III`) are `ID`s and the second-level columns are corresponding `METRIC`s (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`). I would like to reshape it to the following

```
METRIC               a    b    c    d
ID
I      2015-08-01    0    1    2    3
       2015-08-02    4    5    6    7
       2015-08-03    8    9    10   11
II     2015-08-01    20   21   22   23
       2015-08-02    24   25   26   27
       2015-08-03    28   29   30   31
III    2015-08-01    40   41   42   43
       2015-08-02    44   45   46   47
       2015-08-03    48   49   50   51
```

I have (unsuccessfully) looked into using `.pivot`, `.stack`, and `.melt`, but they don't give me what I am looking for. I currently loop over `ID`s and build a *list* of dataframes and `concat` them together as a new dataframe to get what I want.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's use `stack`, `swaplevel` and `sort_index`:

```
df.stack(0).swaplevel(0,1).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
METRIC           a   b   c   d
ID                            
I   2015-08-01   0   1   2   3
    2015-08-02   4   5   6   7
    2015-08-03   8   9  10  11
II  2015-08-01  20  21  22  23
    2015-08-02  24  25  26  27
    2015-08-03  28  29  30  31
III 2015-08-01  40  41  42  43
    2015-08-02  44  45  46  47
    2015-08-03  48  49  50  51
```

Comment: Simple and Clear!!

Comment: @Wen yes it is :-)

Comment: Thank you. It took me a while to understand the process, but now it makes sense. Nice solution :)
Quick question: in my original dataframe, some `ID`s (say, `V`) have rows (say, at `2015-08-02`) where all `METRIC`s are `NaN`s; these get removed by this solution. Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

You can let `transpose` or `T` do some of the work for you.

```
df.T.stack().unstack(1)

METRIC           a   b   c   d
ID                            
I   2015-08-01   0   1   2   3
    2015-08-02   4   5   6   7
    2015-08-03   8   9  10  11
II  2015-08-01  20  21  22  23
    2015-08-02  24  25  26  27
    2015-08-03  28  29  30  31
III 2015-08-01  40  41  42  43
    2015-08-02  44  45  46  47
    2015-08-03  48  49  50  51
```

Comment: Oooh.. I like using T here!   Nice, Mr. piRSquared!  +1

Comment: Thank you. I tried transposing at first, but I'm still not comfortable with using `stack` and `unstack`, so I couldn't figure out how to reorder things. This solution is very concise and nice.
Quick question: in my original dataframe, some `ID`s (say, `V`) have rows (say, at `2015-08-02`) where all `METRIC`s are `NaN`s; these get removed by this solution. Why is that?

Comment: @darXider `stack` takes levels from the columns object into the index object.  When it does, it drops nulls.  You can avoid that by `stack(dropna=False)`

Answer (score 0):

Using @piRSquared's method, we can skip the transpose, just  `df.unstack().unstack(1)`