# Need help Manipulating a dataset for panelOLS regression in Python

Tags: python

My dataset is in an odd format and I have no clue how to fix it (I have tried and read a lot of similar questions but to no avail). Each column is a firm name (e.g. AAPL, AMZN, FB) and the first row is a list of each category of data. Basically each column has a firm name, then the entry below is a code (e.g. trading volume, market value, price), and then the respective data with an index of dates (monthly). How can I appropriately manipulate this so I can filter the data for a panel regression? Example: using each column of trading volume regressed on each column of earnings per share?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may need to learn how to [select columns from Pandas MultiIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470323/selecting-columns-from-pandas-multiindex/54337009#54337009), and perhaps how to [create a MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html). You may also benefit from learning how to [reshape your data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015744/reshaping-a-multiindex-pandas-dataframe) in order to run your panel regression.

If you provide a small sample of your data with the correct format, it will be easier to provide more specifics.